# How to add login attempt count to jQuery login

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a very simple login sample I need to add 3 times login authorized check process. If the user enters more than 3 times error login info then the `.bye` class will pops up! How can I do this?

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ZEb4a/1/).

And here is the code:

```
<form id="target" action="">User Name:
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
    <br />Password :
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p class="error">Login Failed</p>
<p class="correct"></p>
<p class="bye">You Have To Go!</p>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var users = ["user1", "user2", "user3"];
    var passes = ["Pass1", "Pass1", "Pass1"];
    $("#user, #pass ").on("click",function(){
   $(".error").slideUp()
});
    $("#target").submit(function (event) {
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        correctUser = $.inArray(user, users);
        correctPass = $.inArray(pass, passes);
        if (correctUser == 0 || correctPass == 0) {
            $(".error").slideUp();
            $(".correct").html("Welcomw " + user).slideDown();
            $("#user").val('');
            $("#pass").val('');
        } else {
            $(".error").slideDown();
            $("#user").val('');
            $("#pass").val('');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZEb4a/4/ demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEb4a/5/

pretty much the same as @BluAngel but with some bug fixes.
For instance you can log in with any name or password as long as the name or the password is valid, user1 could use the password bobcat if he wanted for instance.

Comment: @ThomasLindvall nice. your comment should be in answer (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEb4a/5/

my fiddle contained some additional fixes and I'll explain it step by step.

```
if (correctUser === 0 && correctPass === 0) {
//do something
}
```

the || operator is a OR [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), the way it was used meant that no matter what you wrote in as long as either the password or the username was correct.
The other thing here is the == which evaluates if the two values are the same, there's one problem here, it only checks the values, it doesn't care about the type.

To check if it is the correct type as well (I.E someone could set correct user to be "0" and it would work) well have to use the === operator.
more [here](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2009/11/javascripts-evil-equality-twins.html).

The problem still persists even though we corrected this minor problem, a client might chose to say that the variable correctPass should be = 0 anyway and then our check has failed, to solve this you'll need to check it on the server but that's a different question.

Other things to keep in mind is that the values are changeable for the client, so even if a client locks himself out, he'll just refresh and he'll get 3 new tries or he can simply manipulate the global count or times value to get pretty much unlimited log in tries (he or she could theoretically set the value to -9999999).

Answer (score 3):

You can have a global `count` variable and just incitement it value every time a login is attempted. Then add the following code in your else condition to check the attempt number.

```
else {
            count++;
            if(count<=3){
                $(".error").slideDown();
                $("#user").val('');
                $("#pass").val('');
            }
            else{
            $(".error").slideUp();
                $("#user").val('');
                $("#pass").val('');
                $(".bye").slideDown();
               $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
            }
        }
```

Here is a updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEb4a/6/).

**PS: Never rely on only client side javascript validation(and have a proper check on the server side), as it can always be beaten**

Comment: thanks Shiva I guess I just have to update the if condition with Thomas idea

Comment: @MonaCoder: ya sure , there are always different ways of doing things, and the points Thomas pointed out are exactly the reason that I mentioned in Bold to never trust client side validation completely